# Any css prefixed with [dir] doesn't work

Tags: magento2.4.3

I've added my css and it's imported and working successfully except the css that is prefixed with the attribute [dir] like:

```
[dir] .gslide-title {
    text-align: center
}
```

Comment: specify the issues in some more details.

Comment: I've added my css to my magento project and it's working except the classes that starts with [dir]

Comment: this does not work in this way.

Comment: it works fine in the index.html, it just doesn't work on magento

Comment: Can you please share the piece of HTML code that should be affected by the given CSS selector?